# PHP GD Image does not show up correctly

Tags: php, image, text, gd

okay, so im using this piece of code:

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'font.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

and i have GD installed.

but the results show me this:

[image]

any idea why?

Comment: Several functions have return values (e.g., `imagejpeg` returns `FALSE` on error). Start with debugging by looking where the functions fail.

Comment: Please improve your title

Comment: In addition to debugging like @MarcelKorpel said, you should remove the header and check if any error messages appear.